# Frutiger font in TexLive 2011 and Lion OS

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, mac

I tried to install the Frutiger font on TexLive 2011 using Lion OS. I followed this guide:

1. Copy the file frutiger.tar.gz to the folder `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.
2. Unzip the file.
3. Open a shell and execute:

   ```
   sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/dvips/base/frutiger.map
   ```

When I try to generate a PDF that uses Frutiger font, I get the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file pfrr8r): Font pfrr8r at 540 not found

 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Any hints how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also execute the command `sudo mktexlsr` or, equivalently, `sudo texhash`?

**Additional suggestion:** Do you maybe have an older version of some TeX installation floating around somewhere on your system? The reason I ask is that the error message mentions /usr/texbin/pdflatex, whereas the executables of MacTeX2011 should be located somewhere under /usr/local/texlive/2011/...

**Third and final suggestion** :-) Have you specified the `T1` font encoding in your TeX program? (I believe the Frutiger fonts from the CTAN only work with T1, and maybe TS1.) If this doesn't work, I give up! Hopefully, others will come up with better suggestions. OK: here's a final suggestion: You should provide a MWE of your problems, so that others can at least try to replicate it.

Comment: Yes both of them.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It is a brand new macbook and i only installed MacTex2011 and nothing else. But how can I double check it?

Comment: On the Mac, `/usr/texbin` is (roughly) a symbolic link to the currently chosen tex distribution. It will ultimately resolve correctly to the relevant texlive directory. So seeing `/usr/texbin` in the log is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know where I can find this T1 font encoding in TexShop or TexWorks? I didn't find it in the preferences.

Comment: One specifies the "T1" font encoding by issuing the command `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the document's preamble.