# What font packages are installed in TeX live?

Tags: fonts, texlive, big-list

What font packages are installed in a full installation of TeX live? Which are obsolete?  Example: `\usepackage{mathpazo}` brings Palatino as the roman font. The `times` package seems to be obsolete (as noted in [l2tabuen](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/)). I only ask for "easy to use" packages to be used with `\usepackage{...}`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

***This answer is a community answer, everyone can edit.***

---

### Fonts accessible with a simple `\usepackage{〈font〉}` call:

*(*) means that the package makes this font the default text font.*

- [`arev`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arev) - Arev, a sans-serif font (*) with math enhancements; derived from Bitstream Vera Sans
- [`avant`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - Sets the sans-serif font to Avant Garde
- [`bera`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bera) - Bera Serif (roman,*), Bera Sans (sans-serif), Bera Mono (typewriter); derived from Bitstream Vera; math font: Computer Modern
- [`bookman`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - roman font: Bookman (*), sans-serif font: Avant Garde, typewriter font: Courier
- [`cabin`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cabin) - Sets the sans-serif font to Cabin
- [`chancery`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - roman font: Chancery (*)
- [`charter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - roman font: Charter (*)
- [`cmbright`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmbright) - CM Bright, lighter sans-serif variant of Computer Modern Sans Serif (sans-serif, *), CM Typwewriter Light (typewriter)
- [`concrete`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/concrete) - Concrete Roman (roman,*) with Euler (math)
- [`courier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - typewriter font: Courier
- [`dejavu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dejavu) - DejaVu Serif (roman,*), DejaVu Sans (sans-serif), DejaVu Sans Mono (typewriter); derived from Bitstream Vera
- [`droid`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/droid) - Droid Serif (roman,*), Droid Sans (sans-serif), Droid Sans Mono(typewriter)
- [`drm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/drm) - complete family of fonts written in Metafont and also available as Type1
- [`ebgaramond`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond) - roman font: EB Garamond (*)
- `euler` - Math font
- [`fourier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier) - Sets the serif font to Adobe Utopia (*) and the math font to Fourier (designed to be compatible with Utopia)
- [`fouriernc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fouriernc) Sets the serif font to (a clone of) NewCentury Schoolbook (*) and the math font to Fouriernc (designed to be compatible with NewCentury)
- [`gentium-tug`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gentium-tug) - SIL Gentium (type1)
- [`helvet`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - Helvetica
- [`inconsolata`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata) - set typewriter font to inconsolata
- [`kpfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts) - roman (*), sans-serif and typewriter font from the Kepler Project, text and math symbols
- [`lato`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lato) - sans-serif font
- [`libertineotf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) (obsolete) - (Open Type) Linux Libertine (roman,*), Linux Biolinum (sans-serif), and Libertine Mono (typewriter)
- [`libertine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine-legacy) - (Type 1 & Open Type) Linux Libertine (roman,*) and Linux Biolinum (sans-serif), and Libertine Mono (typewriter)
- [`librebaskerville`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/librebaskerville) - roman font: Libre Baskerville (*)
- `lmodern` - almost identical fonts to Computer Modern (the default TeX fonts), but in Type1 format (outline).
- [`mathdesign`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign) - text and maths fonts, versions for Charter, Garamond and Utopia.
- [`mathpazo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - changes roman font to Palatino (*), math to something matching.
- [`mathptmx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - roman font is Times (*), math is basically Times Italic, with the missing math symbols coming from Computer Modern, RSFS (for `\mathcal`) and Adobe Symbol
- [`newcent`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) - roman font: New Century Schoolbook (*), sans-serif: Avant Garde, typewriter: Courier
- [`newtx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) Provides, with the package `newtxtext` Young Ryu's TXfonts, but with modified metrics (*=Times Roman). Similarly, `newtxmath` provides the TXfonts math companion fonts with modified metrics. The sans-serif font is based on Helvetica and the typewriter font is especially created.
- [`quattrocento`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quattrocento) - Quattrocento (roman,*), Quattrocento Sans (sans-serif)
- [`tgadventor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the sans-serif font to TeX Gyre Adventor (clone of AvantGarde)
- [`tgbonum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the serif font to TeX Gyre Bonum (clone of Bookman,*)
- [`tgchorus`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the serif font to TeX Gyre Chorus (clone of Zapf Chancery,*)
- [`tgcursor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the typewriter type font to TeX Gyre Cursor (clone of Courier)
- [`tgheros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the sans-serif font to TeX Gyre Heros (clone of Helvetica)
- [`tgpagella`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the serif font to TeX Gyre Pagella (clone of Palatino,*)
- [`tgschola`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the serif font to TeX Gyre Schola (clone of New Century Schoolbook,*)
- [`tgtermes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) Sets the serif font to TeX Gyre Termes (clone of Times,*)
- [`times`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) (obsolete) - changes roman to Times (*), sans-serif to Helvetica and typewriter to Courier
- [`yfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/yfonts) - provides Yiannis Haralambous's rendering of Fraktur, Schwabacher and Gotische and a set of beautiful initials.

---

### Fonts not accessible with a simple `\usepackage{〈font〉}` call:

- [`Computer Modern`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm) - Knuth's original fonts, still "embedded" in Knuth's plain format
- [`frutiger`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/truetypemetrics/frutiger) - a sans-serif typeface with the rationality and cleanliness of Univers, but with the organic and proportional aspects of Gill Sans ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frutiger)), [extra installation steps required](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28658/8057)
- [`gentium`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gentium) - SIL gentium multilingual text font (TrueType)

  - *but see `gentium-tug` above*
- [`luximono`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luximono) - a family of general-purpose monospaced fonts, [extra installation steps required](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22157/8057)

Comment: I don't have the time to do right now, but this might be more clearly arranged as a `<pre>`-table? One column each for serif, sans-serif, typewriter, math, and what the font is a clone of.

Comment: It should be mentioned that for instance `newtx` is not yet available for regular users of TeXLive. Either you run a development snapshot, or you wait for TeXLive 2012 (shouldn't be far out).

Comment: How can gentium be used as default font with pdflatex from texlive 2012? Somehow gentium is included in texlive but cannot be accessed with \usepackage{gentium}. Thx.

Answer (score 21):

Note the existence of [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Note also that I planned to provide two resources as part of a single answer. However, the site says I cannot do this so I'm going to split them up.

The following resource may be of interest.

1. A 1 page (double-sided) list of font packages. All packages are included in TeX Live. Not all fonts are listed, but many are, including several not included in the [list above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59405/).

## List of font packages

### Enhanced Computer Modern, PSNFSS & alternatives, 'Complete' solutions

[image: font packages: side 1]

### Individual font families

[image: font packages: side 2]

## Code: List of font packages

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
%% Copyright 2015 cfr
% \listfiles
\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass[a4paper,welsh,british,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[tt=lining]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{enumitem,geometry,url}
\usepackage{csquotes}
   \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
   \MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\geometry{scale=.9}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\urlstyle{sf}
\title{\LaTeX{} Font Packages}
\author{cfr}
\date{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf[cf]{%
  Browse The \LaTeX{} Font Catalogue at \url{www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/}.
  CTAN topic at \url{ctan.org/topic/font}.}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\pdfinfo{%
  /Title    (LaTeX Font Packages)
  /Subject  (LaTeX)
  /Keywords (LaTeX, package, fonts)}
\pdfcatalog{%
  /PageMode /UseOutlines}   % other values: /UseNone, /UseOutlines, /UseThumbs, /FullScreen
%[openaction <actionspec>]
\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}
\newlist{pkgdescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[pkgdescription]{font=\bfseries\ttfamily}
\newcommand*\lpack[1]{\texttt{\bfseries #1}}
\newlist{fontopts}{description}{1}
\setlist[fontopts]{format=\bfseries\addcolon}
\newcommand*\addcolon[1]{#1:}
\newcommand*\seealso[1]{\emph{See also \emph{#1}.}}
% \noindent Ref.: \url{www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/}\medskip\par
\noindent A ‘complete solution’ provides serif (roman), sans and typewriter text, matching maths, and \LaTeX{} package(s).\medskip\par
\noindent By default, \TeX{} uses encoding \verb|OT1| which is generally non-ideal.
\verb|\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}| will usually avoid this.
\section{Enhanced Computer Modern}\label{sec:cm}
Computer Modern is \TeX's built-in complete solution.
\begin{fontopts}
  \item[Computer Modern Bright] A sans family.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[cmbright] for maths and text.
    Intended for documents where the default family is sans-serif.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Concrete] A serif family.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[concmath] for maths and text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Latin Modern] Enhanced versions of \TeX's default Computer Modern from the GUST e-foundry.
  These packages provide complete solutions.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[lmodern] provides a standard set\-up.
    \item[cfr-lm] offers enhanced support.
    Load with \verb|rm=lining|, \verb|sf=lining| and/or \verb|tt={lining,monowidth}| for lining figures and mono-spaced typewriter.
    The package loads \lpack{nfssext-cfr} which provides commands for accessing the weights, shapes and styles of Latin Modern not supported by \lpack{lmodern}.
  \end{pkgdescription}
\end{fontopts}
\section{PSNFSS \& Alternatives}\label{sec:ps35}
‘Base 35’ refers to the set of 35 PostScript fonts provided by Level 2 PostScript printers and Ghostscript.
These are not complete solutions but can be combined to provide them.
\begin{fontopts}
  \item[psnfss] supports the ‘Base 35’ and some extras.
  The \LaTeX{} packages support clones of the PostScript fonts as follows: \lpack{avant} (ITC Avant Garde Gothic), \lpack{bookman} (ITC Bookman with Avant Garde and Courier), \lpack{chancery} (ITC Zapf Chancery(R)), \lpack{charter} (Bitstream Charter), \lpack{courier} (Courier), \lpack{helvet} (Helvetica), \lpack{mathpazo} (Palatino), \lpack{mathptmx} (Times (New) Roman), \lpack{newcent} (New Century Schoolbook with Avant Garde and Courier).
  \lpack{pifont} supports symbol fonts (e.g.~Symbol, Zapf Dingbats.).
  See below for further options and alternative support.
  The package documentation explains the various options for customising and combining these fonts.
  \item[TeX Gyre (TG) Collection] A remake and extension of the standard PostScript fonts, with \LaTeX{} support, from the GUST e-foundry.
  The \LaTeX{} packages support clones of PostScript fonts as follows: \lpack{tgadventor} (ITC Avant Garde Gothic), \lpack{tgbonum} (ITC Bookman), \lpack{tgchorus} (ITC Zapf Chancery(R)), \lpack{tgcursor} (Courier), \lpack{tgheros} (Helvetica), \lpack{tgpagella} (Palatino), \lpack{tgtermes} (Times (New) Roman), \lpack{tgschola} (Century Schoolbook).
  Details at \url{www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/}.
\end{fontopts}
Here is a partial listing by font:
\begin{fontopts}
  \item[Charter BT] Bitstream Charter.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[mathdesign] with option \verb|charter| offers text and maths.
    \item[XCharter] supports an extension by Michael Sharpe.
    See documentation for loading options.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Erewhon] An extended version of Heuristica.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[erewhon] with options \verb|proportional,scaled=1.064|.
    Add \lpack{newtxmath} with \verb|erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims| for maths.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Heuristica] An extended version of Utopia.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[heuristica] for text.
    Load \lpack{newtxmath} with options \verb|heuristica,vvarbb,bigdelims| for maths.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Kerkis] An extension of Bookman.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[kerkis] for text.
    Load \lpack{kmath} \emph{before} \lpack{kerkis} for maths.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[URW Nimbus Roman] Times clone.
  \seealso{New TX}
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[mathptmx] provides support for maths and text.
    Add \lpack{helvet} with option \verb|scaled=.90| and \lpack{courier} for matching sans and typewriter.
    \item[txfonts] provides a complete solution for maths and text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[URW Palladio] Palatino clone.
  \seealso{New PX}
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[mathpazo] provides text and maths support.
    Load with option \verb|sc| and add \verb|\linespread{1.05}|.
    \item[pxfonts] provides a complete solution for maths and text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[URW Schoolbook L] New Century Schoolbook clone.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[fouriernc] supports text and maths.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Utopia] Adobe Utopia.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[fourier] provides support for maths and text.
    \item[mathdesign] with option \verb|utopia| offers maths and text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
\end{fontopts}
\section{Complete Font Solutions}\label{sec:complete}
Alternatives to Computer Modern or Latin Modern.
\begin{fontopts}
  \item[Kp-Fonts] Inspired by Johannes Kepler.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[kpfonts] supports text and maths with \emph{many} options.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[New PX] An update of PX Fonts using TeX Gyre fonts.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[newpxtext,newpxmath] support text and maths.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[New TX] An update of TX Fonts using TeX Gyre fonts.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[newtxtext,newtxmath] support text and maths.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[PX Fonts] See \lpack{pxfonts} above.
  \item[TX Fonts] See \lpack{txfonts} above.
\end{fontopts}
\section{Individual Font Families}\label{sec:ind}
Complete solutions rely on judicious combinations.
\begin{fontopts}
  \item[Alegreya] Serif, sans and small-caps.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[Alegreya,AlegreyaSans] for text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Antykwa Poltawskiego] A serif family in several weights.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[antpolt] for text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Antykwa Toruńska] A serif family.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[anttor] with option \verb|math| for text and maths.
    Light and condensed options.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Arkandis] Hirwen Harendal's collection.
  \LaTeX{} packages: \lpack{accanthis} (Accan\-this No3 serif), \lpack{adfarrows} (Arrows ADF), \lpack{adforn} (Ornements ADF), \lpack{adfbullets} (Bullets ADF), \lpack{berenis} (Berenis ADF Pro serif with custom Welsh support), \lpack{baskervald} (Baskervald ADF serif), \lpack{electrum} (Electrum ADF serif), \lpack{gillius} (Gillius ADF sans), \lpack{gillius2} (Gill\-ius ADF No Two sans), \lpack{libris} (Libris ADF sans), \lpack{mintspirit} (Mint Spirit sans), \lpack{mintspirit2} (Mint Spirit No Two sans), \lpack{romande} (Romande ADF serif), \lpack{universalis} (Universalis sans), \lpack{venturis} (Venturis ADF serif, sans and titling), \lpack{venturis2} (Venturis ADF No2 serif, sans and titling), \lpack{venturisold} (Venturis Old ADF serif and titling).
  \lpack{Baskervaldx} supports Michael Sharpe's extension of Baskervald ADF.
  \item[Bitstream Vera] Several derivatives are provided.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[arev] supports Arev Sans with Bera Mono for text and maths.
    Note this sets both sans and serif to Arev Sans.
    For Bera Serif, load \lpack{beraserif} \emph{after} \lpack{arev}.
    \item[bera] supports Bera Serif, Sans and Mono text.
    Use \lpack{beraserif}, \lpack{berasans} or \lpack{beramono} for single families.
    \item[dejavu] supports DejaVuSerif DejaVuSans and De\-ja\-Vu\-Sans\-Mono for text.
    Options include condensed.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[BrushScriptX-Italic] Simulated hand-written script.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[pbsi] defines \verb|\bsifamily| and \verb|\textbsi{}|.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Cabin] A humanist font with a condensed variant.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[cabin] installs the font for sans text.
    Various options.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Droid] Droid Serif, Sans and Sans Mono created for Google.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[droid] supports text.
    Options and alternate packages.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[EB Garamond] One version of Garamond.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[ebgaramond-maths] supports text and limited maths.
    Load \lpack{newtxmath} with options \verb|cmintegrals| and \verb|cmbraces| \emph{before} \lpack{ebgaramond-maths}.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Fira] A sans-serif family.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[FiraSans] supports sans text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Gentium] SIL serif family.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[gentium] for the \TeX{} User Group derivative in text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Greek Font Society] A collection of fonts for Greek.
  Many support Latin script, making them suitable for Western European languages such as English.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[gfsartemisia] GFS Artemisia Latin and Greek script with \lpack{txfonts} maths.
    \item[gfsartemisiaeuler] GFS Artemisia Latin and Greek with \lpack{euler} maths.
    \item[gfsbaskerville] GFS Baskerville Greek script.
    \item[gfsbodoni] GFS Bodoni Latin and Greek script.
    \item[gfscomplutum] GFS Complutum Greek script.
    \item[gfsdidot] GFS Didot Latin and Greek script and maths.
    \item[gfsneohellenic] GFS Neohellenic Latin and Greek script and maths.
    \item[gfsporson] GFS Porson Greek script.
    \item[gfssolomos] GFS Solomos Greek script.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Inconsolata] A typewriter font.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[zi4] installs the font for typewriter text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Initials] 23 varieties of decorative initials.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[cfr-initials] 23 \LaTeX{} packages e.g.~for use with \lpack{lettrine}.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Iwona] A derivative of Kurier.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[iwona] for text and maths.
    Light and condensed options.
    This loads Iwona as the default \emph{serif} family.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Kurier] A ‘two-element sans-serif typeface’.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[kurier] for text and maths.
    Light and condensed options.
    This loads Kurier as the default \emph{serif} family.
  \end{pkgdescription}
   \item[Libre Baskerville] A serif family by Pablo Impallari.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[librebaskerville] supports text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
   \item[Libre Caslon] A serif family by Pablo Impallari.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[librecaslon] supports text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Linux Libertine \& Linux Biolinum] Libertine Roman, Biolinum and Libertine Mono.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[libertine] provides support for text.
    Single families may be activated using options or alternate packages.
  \end{pkgdescription}
   \item[Lobster Two] A script family by Pablo Impallari.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[LobsterTwo] defines \verb|\LobsterTwo| to activate the script.
    Load \lpack{LobsterTwo} \emph{before} your main font package, if applicable.
    Otherwise, if using the default fonts, write \verb|\renewcommand*\rmdefault{cmr}|.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[ParaType] PT Serif, PT Sans and PT Mono.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[paratype] provides support for text.
    The package loads \lpack{PTSerif}, \lpack{PTSans} and \lpack{PTMono} which individually do what you'd expect.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[Roboto] ‘A new type family for robots and humans.’
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[roboto] supports sans text.
  \end{pkgdescription}
  \item[STIX] Comprehensive font project.
  \begin{pkgdescription}
    \item[newtxsf] supports sans maths.
    Intended for documents using matching sans families for body text.
    \item[stix] supports serif text and maths.
  \end{pkgdescription}
\end{fontopts}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20):

Please read [part 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249139/) first.

This is the second resource which may be of interest.

2. A 1 page (double-sided) font sampler. Most fonts are supported by packages in TeX Live, but some require the use of the `getnonfreefonts` script. The sample Tengwar font at the very end is the only example not installed by default or easily installed using the script. Note that no attempt is made to show the possibilities offered by all packages or all fonts. Instead, certain fonts and packages are used to illustrate what is possible. Although there is obviously a certain amount of common ground, this sampler does not correspond perfectly with the list of packages, and it is not intended to so correspond. In the choice of fonts used for more extended illustrations, there is some bias towards my own packages. This is certainly not because I think they are better. They are just easier and less time-consuming for me to use.

## Font sampler

[image: font sampler: side 1]

[image: font sampler: side 2]

## Code: Font sampler

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
%% Copyright 2015 cfr
% \listfiles
\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass[a4paper,welsh,british,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[tt=lining]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage[B1,LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Acorn, AnnSton, ArtNouv, ArtNouvc, Carrickc, Eichenla, Eileen, EileenBl, Elzevier, GotIn, GoudyIn, Kinigcap, Konanur, Kramer, MorrisIn, Nouveaud, Romantik, Rothdn, Royal, Sanremo, Starburst, Typocaps, Zallman}
\usepackage{auncial,aurical,pifont,adforn}
\usepackage[all]{tengwarscript}
\newcommand{\test}[1][]{% straight from tengfonts.tex
\vbox{
  {#1\Ttelco}\TTacute\Tlambe\Ts
  {#1\Tampa}\TTacute\Tlambe\TTrightcurl\Tthuule\Ts
  {#1\Tmalta}\TTleftcurl\Toore\Tthuule\TTtwodotsbelow\TTdoubleacute\Tlambe\TTthreedots\Tungwe\TTrightcurl\Ts
  {#1\Thyarmen}\TTdot\Tando\TTnasalizer\TTdoubleleftcurl\Ts
  {#1\Tquesse}\TTrightcurl\Tmalta\Taara\TTdot\Ttelco\TTthreedots\Ts
  {#1\Tformen}\TTacute\Tlambe\TTdot\Tthuule\Ts
  {#1\Tquesse}\TTthreedots\Toore\Tando\TTdot\Talda\TTrightcurl\Ts
  {#1\Ttelco}\TTbreve\Ts
  {#1\Tquesse}\TTdot\Tvala\TTdot\Ts\Tcolon\Ts
  {#1\Tlambe}\TTthreedots\Ts
  {#1\Tthuule}\TTdot\Tungwe\TTlefttilde\TTacute\Tnoldo\TTthreedots\Ts
  {#1\Ttelco}\TTacute\Tnuumen\Thwesta\TTrightcurl\Tanca\TTthreedots\Tando\TTthreedots\Ts
  {#1\Tando}\TTacute\Tlambe\Ts
  {#1\Tformen}\Tuure\TTthreedots\Tsilme\Ttinco\TTrightcurl\Ts
  {#1\Troomen}\Tyanta\TTacute\Ts
  {#1\Tcalma}\TTdot\Tnuumen\TTrightcurl\Ts
  {#1\Ttinco}\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTthreedots\Tumbar\TTthreedots\Ts
  {#1\Ttelco}\TTacute\Tlambe\Ts
  {#1\Troomen}\TTthreedots\Toore\TTrightcurl\Ts
  {#1\Tsilmenuquerna}\TTthreedots\Tquesse\Tlefthook\TTrightcurl\Tformen\TTdoublerightcurl\Tnuumen\Ts
  {#1\Tando}\TTacute\Ts
  {#1\Thyarmen}\TTtwodotsbelow\TTacute\Troomen\TTrightcurl\Ts
  {#1\Tando}\TTacute\Ttinco\Troomen\Taara\TTthreedots\Trighthook\Ts
  {#1\Tando}\TTacute\Tlambe\Ts
  {#1\Tparma}\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTacute\Tquesse\TTnasalizer\TTacute\Ts\Tcolon\Tcenteredlongtilde
}}
\usepackage{geometry,url,xparse,expl3,parskip}
\geometry{scale=.9,nohead,marginparwidth=0pt,marginparsep=0pt}
\urlstyle{sf}
\title{\LaTeX{} Font Sampler}
\author{cfr}
\date{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf[cf]{%
  \footnotesize
  Weight, shape \& style variations are illustrations only.
  Sampler is not exhaustive.
  Fonts may require \texttt{getnonfreefonts-sys}.}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_cfr_first_bool
\NewDocumentCommand \buledeto {}{
  \bool_set_true:N \l_cfr_first_bool
}
\buledeto
\keys_define:nn { cfr / ffontiau / enw } {
  encoding .tl_set:N = \l_cfr_encoding_tl,
  encoding .initial:n = {T1},
  series .tl_set:N = \l_cfr_series_tl,
  series .initial:n = {m},
  shape .tl_set:N = \l_cfr_shape_tl,
  shape .initial:n = {n},
}
\NewDocumentCommand \enwffont { o m m O {} o !g !g } {%
  \group_begin:
  \IfValueT { #1 } {\keys_set:nn { cfr / ffontiau / enw } { #1 }}
  \normalfont
  \bool_if:NT \l_cfr_first_bool {\textbullet{}~}
  \fontencoding{\l_cfr_encoding_tl}
  \fontfamily{#2}
  \fontseries{\l_cfr_series_tl}
  \fontshape{\l_cfr_shape_tl}
  \selectfont #3~
  \IfValueTF { #5 }{
    \keys_set:nn { cfr / ffontiau / enw } { #5 }
    \IfValueTF { #6 } {
      {
        \fontencoding{\l_cfr_encoding_tl}
        \fontfamily{#6}
        \fontseries{\l_cfr_series_tl}
        \fontshape{\l_cfr_shape_tl}
        \selectfont
        \IfValueTF { #7 }{ #7~ }{ #3~ }
      }
    }{
      {
        \fontencoding{\l_cfr_encoding_tl}
        \fontfamily{#2}
        \fontseries{\l_cfr_series_tl}
        \fontshape{\l_cfr_shape_tl}
        \selectfont
        \IfValueTF { #7 }{ #7~ }{ #3~ }
      }
    }
  }{
    \IfValueT { #6 } {
      {
        \fontfamily{#6}
        \selectfont
        \IfValueTF { #7 }{ #7~ }{ #3~ }
      }
    }
  }
  \str_if_eq:eeF {#4} {} { #4~ }
  \normalfont\textbullet
  \group_end:
  \bool_set_false:N \l_cfr_first_bool}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\newcommand\rauri{%
  \renewcommand\auri@slant{Rslant}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{myding}
\begin{document}
\pdfinfo{%
  /Title    (LaTeX Font Sampler)
  /Subject  (LaTeX)
  /Keywords (LaTeX, fonts, sampler)}
\pdfcatalog{%
  /PageMode /UseOutlines}   % other values: /UseNone, /UseOutlines, /UseThumbs, /FullScreen
%[openaction <actionspec>]
\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}
\enwffont{cmr}{Computer Modern Roman}
\enwffont{cmdh}{Computer Modern Roman Dunhill}
\enwffont{cmfr}{Computer Modern Fibonacci}
\enwffont{cmss}{Computer Modern Sans}
\enwffont{cmtt}{Computer Modern Typewriter}
\enwffont{cmvtt}{Computer Modern Variable Typewriter}
\enwffont{cmbr}{Computer Modern Bright}
\enwffont{ccr}{Concrete}
\enwffont{clm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\enwffont{clm}{Medium Upright \textit{Italics} \textui{Upright Italics} \textsl{Oblique} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Oblique Small-Caps} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsl{Oblique}} \textsb{Semi-Bold \textsl{Oblique}}}
\enwffont{clmd}{Latin Modern Roman Dunhill}
\enwffont{clmd}{Medium \textsl{Oblique}}
\enwffont{clms}{Latin Modern Sans}
\enwffont{clms}{Medium \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}} {\fontseries{sbc}\selectfont Semi-Bold Condensed \textsl{Oblique}}}
{\footnotesize
  \enwffont{clmqs}{Latin Modern Sans Quotation}
  \enwffont{clmqs}{Medium \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}}}}
\enwffont{clmv}{Latin Modern Variable Typewriter}
\enwffont{clmv}{Medium \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}} \textlg{Light \textsl{Oblique}}}
\enwffont{clmt}{Latin Modern Typewriter}
\enwffont{clmt}{Medium Upright \textit{Italics} \textsl{Oblique} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Oblique Small-Caps} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}} \textlg{Light \textsl{Oblique} \textcd{Condensed \textsl{Oblique}}}}
{\setcounter{myding}{65}%
  \renewcommand\textbullet{\stepcounter{myding}\ding{\themyding}}%
\enwffont{uaq}{URW Antiqua T}
\enwffont[series=l]{pbk}{URW Bookman L}
\enwffont{ptm}{URW Nimbus Roman}
\enwffont{ppl}{URW Palladio}
\enwffont{pnc}{URW Schoolbook L}
\enwffont{pag}{URW Gothic L}
\enwffont{phv}{URW Nimbus Sans L}
\enwffont{pcr}{URW Nimbus Mono L}
\enwffont{pzc}{URW Chancery L}
\enwffont{ugq}{URW Grotesk T}
\enwffont{ugm}{URW GaramondNo8}
\enwffont{ua1}{URW Arial}
\enwffont{ulg}{URW LetterGothic}
\enwffont{uop}{URW Classico}
\enwffont{zgmx}{URW GaramondNo8 Expert}
\enwffont{qag}{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\enwffont{qag}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{qbk}{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\enwffont{qbk}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{qcr}{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\enwffont{qcr}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{qcs}{TeX Gyre Schola}
\enwffont{qcs}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{qhv}{TeX Gyre Heros}
\enwffont{qhv}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{qhvc}{TeX Gyre Heros Condensed}
\enwffont{qhvc}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{qpl}{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\enwffont{qpl}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{qtm}{TeX Gyre Termes}
\enwffont{qtm}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont[shape=it]{qzc}{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\enwffont{put}{Utopia}
\enwffont{Heuristica-TLF}{Heuristica}
\enwffont{erewhon-OsF}{Erewhon}
\enwffont{erewhon-OsF}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps} \textbf{\textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}}}
}%
\enwffont{bch}{Charter BT}% last one in the psnfss group after the end of the group for the bullets to revert properly
\enwffont{jkp}{KP-Fonts Serif}
\enwffont{jkpl}{KP-Fonts Serif Light}
\enwffont{jkpx}{KP-Fonts Serif Extended}
\enwffont{jkpx}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps} \textlg{Light Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}} Medium {\fontseries{sb}\selectfont Semi-Bold Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}} {\fontseries{sbx}\selectfont Semi-Bold Extended Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}} {\fontseries{b}\selectfont Bold Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}} {\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Bold Extended Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}}}[][shape=sc]{jkpxk}{Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique} \textlg{Light Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique}} {\fontseries{sb}\selectfont Semi-Bold Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique}} {\fontseries{sbx}\selectfont Semi-Bold Extended Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique}} {\fontseries{b}\selectfont Bold Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique}} {\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Bold Extended Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique}}}
\enwffont{jkp}{tactful sticklers}{jkpos}{tactful sticklers}
\enwffont{jkpss}{KP-Fonts Sans}
\enwffont{jkpss}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps} {\fontseries{b}\selectfont Bold  \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}} {\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Bold Extended \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique Small-Caps}}}[][shape=sc]{jkpssk}{Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique} {\fontseries{b}\selectfont Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique}} {\fontseries{bx}\selectfont Large Small-Caps {\fontshape{scsl}\selectfont Oblique}}}
\enwffont{jkpss}{tactful sticklers}{jkpssos}{tactful sticklers}
\enwffont{jkptt}{KP-Fonts Typewriter}
\enwffont{jkptt}{Upright \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}}}
\acorn{Acorn} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{Alegreya-OsF}{Alegreya}
\enwffont{AlegreyaSC-TLF}{Alegreya SC}
\enwffont{AlegreyaSans-OsF}{Alegreya Sans}
\enwffont{AlegreyaSansSC-OsF}{Alegreya Sans SC}
\enwffont{AmiciLogo}{AmiciLogo}
\enwffont{AmiciLogo}{Upright \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}}}
\astone{Annston} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{AnonymousPro}{AnonymousPro}
\enwffont{antp}{Antykwa Poltawskiego}
\enwffont{antp}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textlg{Light \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}} \textsb{Semi-Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{antt}{Antykwa Toruńska}
\enwffont{anttc}{Antykwa Toruńska Condensed}
\enwffont{anttl}{Antykwa Toruńska Light}
\enwffont{anttlc}{Antykwa Toruńska Light Condensed}
\enwffont{antt}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textlg{Light \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}} \textsb{Semi-Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}
  {\fontseries{c}\selectfont Condensed \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textlg{\cdwidth Light Condensed \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}} \textsb{\cdwidth Semi-Bold Condensed \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}} {\fontseries{bc}\selectfont Bold Condensed \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}}
{\setcounter{myding}{26}%
  \renewcommand\textbullet{%
    \stepcounter{myding}%
    \ifnum\value{myding}=41\setcounter{myding}{55}%
    \else\ifnum\value{myding}=70\setcounter{myding}{3}\fi\fi
    \adforn{\themyding}}%
\enwffont{AccanthisADFStdNoThree-LF}{AccanthisNo3}
\enwffont[encoding=LY1]{ybd}{BerenisADFPro}
\enwffont[encoding=LY1]{ybd}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps \textit{Italic Small-Caps}} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps \textit{Italic Small-Caps}}}}
\enwffont[encoding=LY1]{ybd}{Queenie, actor-spy and often acclaimed sky-stringer, chuckled at slightly shivering otters in fjords.}{ybdw}{Q*ueenie, actor-spy and often acclaimed sky-stringer, chuckled at slightly shivering otters in fjords.}
\enwffont{ybv}{BaskervaldADF}
\enwffont{ybv}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics}} \texteb{Extra-Bold \textit{Italics}}}
\enwffont{ybv}{Somewhat splendid fjords act last.}{ybvw}{Somewhat splendid fjords act last.}
\enwffont{yes}{ElectrumADF}{yesw}
\enwffont{yes}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Oblique Small-Caps} \textlg{Light  \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Oblique Small-Caps}} \textsb{Semi-Bold  \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Oblique Small-Caps}} \textbf{Bold  \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Oblique Small-Caps}}}
\enwffont{yes}{Queen Q*ueenie acted despite wistful whistling.}{yesw}{Queen Q*ueenie acted despite wistful whistling.}
\enwffont{GilliusADF-LF}{GilliusADF}
\enwffont{GilliusADFNoTwo-LF}{GilliusADFNoTwo}
\enwffont{yly}{LibrisADF}
\enwffont{yly}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics}}}
\enwffont{yly}{Quietly, Rupert X. Kurtis, a churlish skittish bespectacled clerk, strictly slacks.}{ylyw}{Quietly, Rupert X. Kurtis, a churlish skittish bespectacled clerk, strictly slacks.}
\enwffont{MintSpirit-LF}{MintSpiritNoTwo}
\enwffont{yrd}{RomandeADF}{yrdw}
\enwffont{yrd}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textdb{Demi-Bold  \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps}}}
\enwffont{yrd}{Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow. Querulous sponges act last. \swashstyle Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow. Querulous sponges act last.}{yrda}{Querulous sponges act last. Q*uerulous s*ponges* act las*t.  \swashstyle Querulous sponges act last. Q*uerulous s*ponges* act las*t.}
\enwffont{UniversalisADFStd-LF}{Universalis}
\enwffont{yvt}{VenturisADF}
\enwffont{yvt}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Italic Small-Caps} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Italic Small-Caps}} \texteb{Extra-Bold \textit{Italics}} \textcd{Condensed \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Italic Small-Caps} \textbf{\cdwidth Bold Condensed \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} \textsi{Italic Small-Caps}}}}
\enwffont{yvt}{Kinky Querulous \emph{Rhinos} X-Ray Exultant Risque \emph{Zebras}. \scshape Kinky Querulous \emph{Rhinos} X-Ray Exultant Risque \emph{Zebras}. \upshape\swashstyle Kinky Querulous \emph{Rhinos} X-Ray Exultant Risque \emph{Zebras}. \scshape Kinky Querulous \emph{Rhinos} X-Ray Exultant Risque \emph{Zebras}.}{yvtaw}{\upshape Kinky Querulous \emph{Rhinos} X-Ray Exultant Risque \emph{Zebras}.}
\enwffont{yv2}{VenturisADF No2}
\enwffont{yv2}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textmb{Medium-Bold  \textit{Italics}} \textbf{Bold  \textit{Italics}} \texteb{Extra-Bold  \textit{Italics}} \textcd{Condensed  \textit{Italics} \textbf{\cdwidth Bold Condensed \textit{Italics}}}}
\enwffont{yv1}{VenturisADF Sans}
\enwffont{yv1}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textlg{Light  \textit{Italics}} \textdb{Demi-Bold  \textit{Italics}} \textbf{Bold  \textit{Italics}} \texteb{Extra-Bold  \textit{Italics}} \textcd{Condensed  \textit{Italics}} \textbf{\textcd{Bold Condensed  \textit{Italics}}} \textep{Extended  \textit{Italics} \textbf{\epwidth Bold Extended  \textit{Italics}}}}
\enwffont{yv3}{VenturisADF Sans No2}
\enwffont{yv3}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textbf{Bold  \textit{Italics}} \textcd{Condensed  \textit{Italics}} \textbf{\textcd{Bold Condensed  \textit{Italics}}} \textep{Extended  \textit{Italics} \textbf{\epwidth Bold Extended  \textit{Italics}}}}
\enwffont{yvtd}{VenturisADF Titling No2}
\enwffont[shape=ol]{yvtd}{VenturisADF Titling No4}
\enwffont{yv1d}{VenturisADF  Titling No1}
\enwffont[series=b]{yv1d}{VenturisADF  Titling No3}
\enwffont{yvo}{VenturisADF Old}
\enwffont{yvo}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textbf{Bold  \textit{Italics}}}
\enwffont{yvo}{dogs \& sticks \textbf{dogs \& sticks d*ogs* \& sticks*}}
}% last one outside the group for the bullets
\enwffont{yvod}{VenturisADF Goth Titling}
\enwffont[encoding=B1]{auncl}{Artificial Uncial fonts}
\artnouv{ARTNOUV} \textbullet{}
\artnouvc{ArtnouvC} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{augie}{Augie}
\enwffont{AuriocusKalligraphicus}{AuriocusKalligraphicus}
\enwffont{AuriocusKalligraphicus}{Upright \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}}}
\enwffont{fav}{Arev Sans}
\enwffont{fve}{Bera Serif}
\enwffont{fvs}{Bera Sans}
\enwffont{fvm}{Bera Mono}
\enwffont{sqrc}{Bookhands Square Capitals}
\carr{CarrickC} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{DejaVuSerif-TLF}{DejaVuSerif}
\enwffont{DejaVuSans-TLF}{DejaVuSans}
\enwffont{DejaVuSansMono-TLF}{DejaVuSansMono}
\enwffont[series=xl]{pbsi}{BrushScriptX-Italic}
\enwffont{Cabin-TLF}{Cabin}
\enwffont{CabinCondensed-TLF}{Cabin Condensed}
\enwffont{Caladea-TLF}{Caladea}
\enwffont{fca}{Cantarell}
\enwffont{Carlito-TLF}{Carlito}
\enwffont{cmin}{Carolingan Minuscules}
\enwffont{Cinzel-LF}{Cinzel \textbf{Cinzel} \fontseries{k}\selectfont Cinzel}
\enwffont{CinzelDecorative-LF}{Cinzel Decorative \textbf{Cinzell Decorative} \fontseries{k}\selectfont Cinzell Decorative}
\enwffont{ClearSans-LF}{Clear Sans}
\enwffont{ClearSansLight-LF}{Clear Sans Light}
\enwffont{ClearSansThin-LF}{Clear Sans Thin}
\enwffont{fco}{Comfortaa}
\enwffont{cyklop}{Cyklop}
\enwffont{dayrom}{DayRoman}
\enwffont{fdr}{Droid Serif}
\enwffont{fds}{Droid Sans}
% \enwffont{fdm}{Droid Mono}% ddim yn gweithio
\enwffont{EBGaramond-OsF}{EB Garamond}[{\fontfamily{EBGaramondInitials-TLF}\selectfont G}aramond Initials][shape=sw]{EBGaramond-OsF}
\enwffont{EBGaramond-OsF}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italic Small-Caps}}
\enwffont{EBGaramond-OsF}{\textit{A Bad Dodger Gave Klingon Paul Quiet Reason to Strike Torrid Vanquished Wombles Zealously.} {\fontshape{sw}\selectfont A Bad Dodger Gave Klingon Paul Quiet Reason to Strike Torrid Vanquished Wombles Zealously.}}
\eichen{Eichenla} \textbullet{}
\eileen{Eileen} \textbullet{}
\eileenbl{Eileen Black Letter} \textbullet{}
\elz{Elzevier} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{fbb-LF}{fbb}
\enwffont{fbb-LF}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}}
\enwffont{FiraSans-TLF}{Fira}
\enwffont{foekfont}{FOEKFONT}
\enwffont{frc}{French Cursive}
\enwffont{gentium}{Gentium}
\enwffont{gentium}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics}}}
\gotin{GOT INITIALS} \textbullet{}
\goudyin{GOUDY INITIALS} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{artemisia}{GFS Artemisia}
\enwffont{bodoni}{GFS Bodoni}
\enwffont{udidot}{GFS Didot}
\enwffont{neohellenic}{GFS Neohellenic}
\enwffont{zi4}{Inconsolata}
\enwffont{iwona}{Iwona}
\enwffont{iwonac}{Iwona Condensed}
\enwffont{iwonal}{Iwona Light}
\enwffont{iwonalc}{Iwona Light Condensed}
\enwffont{JanaSkrivana}{JanaSkrivana}
\enwffont{JanaSkrivana}{Upright \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}}}
\kinig{Kinig Cap} \textbullet{}
\konanur{Konanur} \textbullet{}
\kramer{KRAMER kramer} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{kurier}{Kurier}
\enwffont{kurierc}{Kurier Condensed}
\enwffont{kurierl}{Kurier Light}
\enwffont{kurierlc}{Kurier Light Condensed}
\enwffont{fla}{Lato}
\enwffont{LibreBaskerville-TLF}{Libre Baskerville}
\enwffont{LibreCaslonText-TLF}{Libre Caslon}
\enwffont{LinuxLibertineT-OsF}{Linux Libertine Roman}
\enwffont{LinuxLibertineDisplayT-OsF}{Linux Libertine Display}
\enwffont{LinuxLibertineInitialsT-OsF}{LINUX LIBERTINE INITIALS}
\enwffont{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}{Linux Biolinum}
\enwffont{LinuxLibertineMonoT-TLF}{Linux Libertine Mono}
\enwffont{LobsterTwo-LF}{Lobster Two}
\enwffont{LukasSvatba}{LukasSvatba}
\enwffont{LukasSvatba}{Upright \textsl{Oblique} \textbf{Bold \textsl{Oblique}}}
\enwffont{ul9}{Luxi Mono}
\enwffont{Merriweather-OsF}{Merriweather}
\enwffont{MerriweatherSans-TLF}{Merriweather Sans}
\morrisin{Morris Initials} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{nanummj}{nanummj}
\enwffont{nanumgt}{nanumgt}
\nouvd{Nouveaud} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{fos}{OpenSans}
\enwffont{Overlock-LF}{Overlock}
\enwffont{OverlockSC-LF}{Overlock SC}
\enwffont{PlayfairDisplay-OsF}{Playfair Display}
\enwffont{PlayfairDisplay-OsF}{Upright \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics} \textbf{Bold \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}} \fontseries{k}\selectfont Black \textit{Italics} \textsc{Small-Caps} {\fontshape{scit}\selectfont Italics}}
\enwffont{PTSerif-TLF}{PT Serif}
\enwffont{PTSerifCaption-TLF}{PT Serif Caption}
\enwffont{PTSans-TLF}{PT Sans}
\enwffont{PTSansNarrow-TLF}{PT Sans Narrow}
\enwffont{PTSansCaption-TLF}{PT Sans Caption}
\enwffont{PTMono-TLF}{PT Mono}
\enwffont{Quattrocento-TLF}{Quattrocento}
\enwffont{QuattrocentoSans-TLF}{Quattrocento Sans}
\enwffont{Raleway-TLF}{Raleway}
\enwffont{Roboto-LF}{Roboto}
\enwffont{RobotoCondensed-LF}{Roboto Condensed}
\enwffont{RobotoSlab-LF}{Roboto Slab}
\romantik{Romantik} \textbullet{}
\roth{ROTH DN roth dn} \textbullet{}
\royal{ROYAL} \textbullet{}
\sanremo{San Remo} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{SourceCodePro-TLF}{SourceCodePro}
\enwffont{SourceSansPro-TLF}{SourceSansPro}
\starburst{Star Burst} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{stix}{STIX}
\enwffont{trjn}{TRAJAN}
\typocap{Typocaps} \textbullet{}
\enwffont{yfrak}{Yannis Fraktur}
\zall{Zallman} \textbullet{}

{\centering
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\tengwarannataritalic\test
\end{minipage}\par
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where are the font packages like Acorn, Annston...? They do not appear in a search on CTAN and are not part of my TeX distribution, which is fairly recent (last few months). help.

Comment: @zun They are included in TeX Live 2014 (and presumably will be in 2015). They are on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials).

Comment: While an interesting concept, I can't find a way to replicate the `Font Sampler` code output with current TeXLive on MacOS. Copying the above code into `fontsampler.tex` and attempting both CLI and various IDE build attempts just results in a slew of errors. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, TeX Live (-full) currently throws an error when executing `pdflatex fonts.tex` with the above code: "! Font T1/LinuxLibertineInitialsT-OsF/m/n/12=LinLinertineIT-osf-t1 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found." Can someone update it so we have an example that runs?