# gentium as font with pdflatex from texlive 2012

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive

How can Gentium be used as default font with `pdflatex` from TeX Live 2012? Somehow Gentium is included in TeX Live but cannot be accessed with `\usepackage{gentium}`, see [What font packages are installed in TeX live?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live/67259).

Comment: Do you have the option to use XeLaTeX? It would make this a lot easier.

Comment: That should be possible. So i rephrase the question: What is the easiest way to  access the gentium font included in texlive 2012 as default font with pdftex/XeLaTeX/Luatex ...?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You should edit your question as well, so that the rephrasing isn't "hidden away" in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

With XeLaTeX, this works for me:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. 
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Of course compile with `xelatex $filename`.