# Free fontfamily with latex

Tags: fonts

I am playing with font type on my report - for that I need the list of font-family which can be used with `pdflatex` without installing any external package.

Comment: I'm not too sure such a list exists - and furthermore I'm not sure that such a list would extend upon the default fonts available through `rm sf tt`.  If you really need to play with fonts, I would check out XeTeX, which allows (nearly) any system font to be used.

Comment: See the question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live

Answer (score 4):

Hope I got your question correct, but a list of fonts and how to use them is in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). But normally all fonts come as a package.