# How can i use fonts other than gbsn/gkai for CJK Chinese?

Tags: fonts, unicode, cjk

The standard CJK package only provides 2 fonts for simplified Chinese, as described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Chinese).

My question is how to create more fonts for it? I'm using MacTeX 2013 and UTF8 + CJK + pdflatex is the expected environment.

There should be a way to convert fonts from, say `ttf`, to fonts TeX could handle.

Comment: Why not simply to use XeLaTeX?

Comment: @m0nhawk I'm using a template provided by others...So actually I have no option.

Comment: Since the process of setting up fonts for the package `CJK/CJKutf8` is *VERY* tedious, I strongly recommend you to use XeTeX with the package `xeCJK`, because the engine XeTeX can use system font directly and the package `xeCJK` support prohibitions (in Chinese: "禁则/禁則") much better.

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Could you describe it below or give me a pointer?

Comment: The `zhmatrics` bundle does provides CJK fonts support for Windows user. It is illegal to provide the actual fonts provided by Chinese version of Windows, but you can use those fonts without complicated configurations if you are a Windows user or you have those Windows fonts installed.

Comment: Have you read the previous solutions about Chinese typesetting? Can you provide more information about your document and your environment? Are you preparing a Chinese document or an English document with only a few Chinese words? What template are you using? Do you wish your document to be compiled by other people? There are various solutions for Chinese typesetting, we need to know more.

Comment: And, is it possible to use dvipdfmx instead of pdfTeX? That's easier to configure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Control sequences and packages about font

### (plain) TeX level control sequences about font

There are several control sequences (or say command) about font in the original TeX (TeX primitive and/or plain TeX level command).

- `\/`, can be used to regulate the space after *italic* characters (see the difference between `{\itshape italic} normal` and `{\itshape italic}\/ normal` in LaTeX).
- `\font` is the original command to call a font. In TeX and pdfTeX, `\font` can only read `tfm` files; in XeTeX, it can read TrueType, AAT or OpenType font files; in LuaTeX, `\font` can only read `tfm` files too, however, having a build-in library named `callback`, LuaTeX could use as many kinds of font files as XeTeX does.
- `\fam` can be used to define math fonts. In original TeX, only 16 kinds of math font can be defined (no limit in XeTeX).
- `\fontname` will return the name of font.
- `\nullfont` provides a font has no character.

pdfTeX and LuaTeX can generate PDF file directly, by using pre-defined `pdfTeX.map` who map a `tfm` font to a Type1 or TrueType font.

- `\pdfmapline`: Taken as an example, `\pdfmapline{cmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb}` will embed `cmr10.pfb` into the PDF file if someone is trying to use `cmr10.tfm`.
- `\pdfpkresolution`: If there is no `.pfb` file, `.pk` file comes to be an alternative. This command is designed to tune the resolution ratio of PK font.

### LaTeX and NFSS

NFSS is short for 'New Font Selection Scheme' (see [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fntguide.pdf)). For the reason that the seven control sequences are quite boring for user, NFSS define five features of font---encoding，family，series，shape and size. Indeed, macros of NFSS use those seven commands as basement.

Although NFSS provides an easier way for users to select font, using NFSS directly could be labeled as obscurity. Another disadvantage of NFSS is that NFSS is designed for western chars.

### Packages

Fortunately, we have package `osf` (ConTeXt style like, see [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/ofs/ofsdoc-e.pdf)) and package `fontspec` (under XeTeX and LuaTeX, see [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)).

Package `xeCJK` (with XeTeX) and package `LuaTeX-ja` (with LuaTeX, see [here](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/luatex-ja/wiki/LuaTeX-ja%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9)) extend the functionality of `fontspec` and handle prohibitions and punctuation compression better.

Since the process of setting up fonts for the package `CJK/CJKutf8` is *VERY* tedious, I strongly recommend you to use XeTeX with the package `xeCJK` or use LuaTeX with the package `LuaTeX-ja`.

---

## Using the engine TeX/pdfTeX (original LaTeX and pdfLaTeX)

### The `CJK` package

The 8-bits TeX system suppose that only 256 (`2**8`) kinds of char would be contained in a `.tex` file. As a result, the `.tfm` font file can have no more than 256 chars. Now, something bad happened---how can an Aisa chars set who, you know, has much more chars, be included in such a file!

Pioneers of TeX divided an Aisa chars set and encoding table into many partitions, and each of them has only 256 chars. Consequently, every index of a single char has two parts: the first part let TeX know which partition should be loaded, and the second part tells TeX the index of the specific char in that partition. And this is what `CJK` did.

#### The process

When you are compiling the following code, what will happen?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{GBK}{song}
汉字
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

When TeX is reading `\begin{CJK}{GBK}{song}`, it will load `UGBK.sfg`. `UGBK.sfg` gives the correspondence of Unicode and GBK, since most Chinese fonts use Unicode inside.

Now, TeX meets '汉字'. These two chars in `CJK` are `\CJKchar[GBK]{"BA}{"BA}\CJKchar[GBK]{"D7}{"D6}`. Here '汉' in GBK is `0xBABA`, and '字' is `OxD7D6`.

When TeX meets \end{CJK}, it will read `UGBK.sfg` and find that '汉' is in the 43rd partition (#199), say subfont, and '字' is in the 65th partition (#105). As a result, '汉字' will be converted to (C19 in `CJK` means GBK):

```
\C19/song/m/n/10/43 ╟\C19/song/m/n/10/65 i
```

Note that, in extended ASCII, `╟` is 199 and `i` is 105. `\C19/song/m/n/10/` means GBK encoding, font name `song`, (m)edium (not blod) and upright (not italic).

In `C19song.fd` (fd is short for 'font description'), you can see:

```
\DeclareFontShape{C19}{song}{m}{n}{<-> CJK * gbksong}{}
```

Consequently, `\C19/song/m/n/10/43 ╟\C19/song/m/n/10/65 i` will set:

```
{\font\1="gbksong43"\1\char199}{\font\1="gbksong65"\1\char105}
```

#### Files

- `.sfg`: Give the correspondence of two encoding.
- `.fd`: Declare which font should be used.
- `.tfm`: Define the abstract part, such as ligature and kern, of a font.
- `.pk`: Define the graphic part, the glyph of a font.
- `.map`: Font mapping.
- `.pfb`: Type1 font style's file.

If you want to use `CJK/CJKutf8`, you have to generated/copy **SOOOOOOOOOO** many kinds of file. So, again, do not use it.

#### Install new font

See [here](http://liam0205.me/attachment/LaTeX-useful-tools/texlivefont-20070828.pdf), by xptao@bbs.ctex.org.

### The `zhmCJK` package

See [here](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=70222), by LeoLiu.

---

## Using the engine XeTeX

**Warning**: The following text described how to use XeLaTeX with package `xeCJK` and `ctex`, as the OP asked me to do, however, it is a little offtopic.

The job typesetting an article or book with Chinese characters can be splitted into three parts---select font, handle prohibitions and layout style. XeLaTeX with the package `xeCJK` solved the first two parts, and `ctex` (case sensitive) package/documentclass settled the last one perfectly.

### XeLaTeX with `xeCJK`

Follow these steps to get correct output:

1. Open system terminal and type `fc-list :lang=zh-cn` (or `fc-list :lang=zh-tw` if you are in Taiwan).
2. One line of that result may look like: `C:/WINDOWS/fonts/SIMLI.TTF: LiSu,隶书:style=Regular`---separated by two colons into three parts. While the first part shows where you can find the specific font file, the second part shows `<file name>` (partitioned by comma(s)), and the last one tells you font style.
3. Select one font, and put its `<file name>` into `\setCJKmainfont{<file name>}` (case sensitive, see example below).
4. Save it as encoding **UTF-8** with filename '`main.tex`', and then, compile it using `XeLaTeX` by `xelatex main.tex`.

Example:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{metalogo} % for the logo of XeLaTeX
\usepackage{showframe} % for showing page frames
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{LiSu}
\begin{document}
这里是中文，这是隶书。我在使用\XeLaTeX 结合xeCJK排版中文。
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Tips:

- You do *not* need to add `~` between CJK character and western character to regulate the space between them, as you always did in `CJK/CJKutf8`.
- With the engine XeTeX, CJK character can be used as a command, so you must leave a space after any command, if it is followed by any CJK character, or an `Undefined control sequence` error will be reported.

### `ctex` package/documentclass

This package provides you features, such as set `\parindent` to EXACTLY two times of the width of Chinese character (`2\ccwd`), to simplify your layout settings. See [its documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ctex/ctex.pdf) of the latest version.

This package set `SimSun`/`KaiTi`, provided by [china-e](http://www.china-e.com.cn/)(中易中标电子信息技术有限公司), as default fonts for user in China mainland, using Windows OS, CN-Simp version. If you have installed these fonts correctly, typesetting Chinese becomes quite easily.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart} % instead of `article'
% `ctexbook' for `book', and `ctexrep' for `report'
\begin{document}
这里是中文。\\
段首缩进两个字符宽度。

这里是默认字体，中易宋体。\textit{这里是楷书}，\texttt{还有仿宋}。
\end{document}
```

If you do not have these fonts, using the `nofonts` option and selecting fonts manually will be a good choice. Here's a example (without text body):

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8, nofonts]{ctexart} 
% select fonts for western chars
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
% select fonts for CJK chars
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont={Adobe Heiti Std},ItalicFont={华文楷体}]
  {华文中宋}
\setCJKsansfont{Adobe Heiti Std}
\setCJKmonofont{华文仿宋}
```

For more information about this issue, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/wiki/UnixFonts).

### Documentations online

The package `fontspec` (xeCJK is based on it): http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf

The package `xeCJK`: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf

The package/documentclass `ctex`: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ctex/ctex.pdf

Comment: It seems that XeTeX is not acceptable.

Comment: @LeoLiu The OP said he/she want a pointer..

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution for you, I guess, is to copy the Windows Chinese fonts

```
simsun.ttc
simfang.ttf
simkai.ttf
simhei.ttf
simli.ttf  (optional)
simyou.ttf (optional)
```

*to the working directory* (if you have bought a Windows copy), and use:

```
% Compile with pdflatex or latex+dvipdfmx
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{CJKspace}

% for font mapping
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\input{zhwinfonts}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{zhsong}

中文排版。

\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

If you don't have a Windows copy, you may need to use some other Chinese fonts in TrueType format. However, the SinoType (华文) fonts preinstalled in Mac OS X cannot be used. See https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=81

Comment: Sorry. Off topic. How to get a list of names of font package provided by TeX distro installed on my Windows machine?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot: See [What font packages are installed in TeX live?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/) and [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)