# Can anyone help me identifying this font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I have been looking for a long time over the internet (and yes I have stumbled here many times) the font or typeface used for example, on the book Physics for Scientists and Engineers, Serway and Jewett,  among many others. I guess this book might have been written in LaTeX, XeTeX, etc. or not. I normally use LaTeX to write my own documents and I have never used any other, so I don't really know if that kind of document may have been typed on another language or software that I am not aware of. I post here an image as an example of the use of the font. I have been looking and I think the font itself resembles to Baskerville but I specially like the math typing and greek letters.

[image: example]

I hope you could help me identify the font and how to get it, and if it's not possible to do in LaTeX how could I create something like this I don't really know if there are other possibilites to type math and do stuff like LaTeX or variants do.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you have access to a PDF, you can inspect the properties for a listing of fonts. If not, there are several other methods. These are all discussed at our question [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  the sum looks very like times, but i haven't time to explore.

Comment: It looks very like Baskerville from here, although the Greek letters appear to be Porson

Comment: For (pdf)TeX, see [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) and maybe [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live), possibly even including my [my font sampler](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249140/).