# Are there more fonts like COPPERPLATE GOTHIC which is an all caps font but the letter typed with Caps ON is slightly larger than the rest of the word?

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for an all caps font where the letter typed with Caps ON is slightly larger than the letters typed with Caps OFF. Copperplate Gothic, light and bold, are the only fonts on Microsoft Word default list which has this feature. Sackers Gothic is the only other font that I found. Are there any more appealing fonts with this feature?

Comment: This is called *Small Caps* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps You can use `\textsc{Foo Here}`

Comment: Are you referring to a font with "small caps"? In such a font all letters are capital letters but uppercase letters are still larger that lowercase letters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps

Comment: The question reads then "Can you tell me the names of **all the fonts** which have small caps", and that is another question ;-)

Comment: If you’re looking for a good revival of Copperplate Gothic that won’t break the bank and are willing to use `fontspec` with `xetex` or `luatex`, try https://cowboycollective.cc/2020/06/22/CopperplateCC.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to name *all of the fonts* that have this property, because there is no comprehensive list of all of the fonts on the planet, complete with their font metrics.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Having small caps _is_ a font property, and not all fonts have them, so why would the list contain "all fonts"?

Comment: You are correct. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for fonts with small-caps, you might find [my font sampler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live/249140#249140) useful, but you should note that it is *not* comprehensive. It is also restricted to fonts which can be easily used with (pdf)TeX i.e. it does not deal with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Doubtless there are better lists but [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) seems not to group fonts according to this particular characteristic.

Note that some packages use *faked* small-caps. These are generally inferior and font designers typically recommend against using them.