# LuaTeX doesn't seem to recognise \fontid

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex, fontspec

In short, I am trying to use a LuaTeX package, and after digging into the error-emitting code have come up with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\font \cmuntt = file:cmuntt.otf
\begin{document}
    \fontid \cmuntt
    \textbf{Zulu \lipsum[1-8]}
\end{document}
```

The font file `cmuntt.otf` is arbitrary in this case, and is otherwise recognised by Lua(La)Tex, but the sequence `\fontid \cmuntt`, dragged verbatim out of the package in question, `typewriter.sty`, doesn't seem to work, and causes the compiler to emit the following error code:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6      \fontid
             \cmuntt
?
```

I'm not sure what is supposed to happen, nor what is actually happening, but it is worrying that the compiler is emitting that error message with what is supposed to be a core LuaTeX control sequence. Replacing `fontspec` with `luaotfload` predictably doesn't change anything.

I am using a (supposedly?) up-to-date MikTeX installation, if it makes a difference.

Comment: On my TeXLive 2017 distribution the snippet compiles with `lualatex` (if I add `\usepackage{lipsum}` to the preamble).

Comment: @marmot how terribly worrying! (I just added `lipsum` to the example, forgot I left it out — but it breaks just before that); and I'm on MikTeX

Comment: Well, with an current complete MiKTeX 2.9 I can compile your code without any error or warning.

Comment: Where is file `typewriter.sty`? I do not find it in my own TeX setup, or CTAN.

Comment: @RobtAll No idea. Perhaps a custom package of the OP's? The MWE doesn't require it, after all.

Comment: @RobtAll Only thing a web search turns up is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383925/what-fonts-are-available-to-me-when-using-usepackaget1fontenc ;).

Comment: Why are you loading `fontspec` and then using TeX-level font macros? Not even LaTeX.

Comment: `typewriter.sty` is this brilliant package at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344214/use-latex-to-simulate-old-typewriter-written-texts

Comment: @cfr I used fontspec to make 10000% sure it wasn't the font file messing up; otherwise, the TeX macros wouldn't be in my actual code, but in the package — and it's those very macros (or, well, specifically \fontid) that cannot work. I'm currently installing TeXLive to see whether it'll fix my issue, but it's a bit like taking a hammer to a brain surgery imho

Comment: But why are you using `\font` etc. at all in LaTeX? You should use the higher level macros, even in a package, unless your package is the package providing those macros, obviously.

Comment: Oh, the purpose of the package is to screw up the typesetting. Fair enough.

Comment: The package itself is using `\font` and `\fontid`; I didn't want to take the whole package apart, and using TeX macros in LaTeX ought to work anyhow; whether I use `\fontid` in the file itself, or do `\include{typewriter}`, the error is the same — but the code is more legible like this and doesn't require taking a look at two separate files.

Comment: take it apart take it apart take it apart

Comment: Works ok for me, show your log-file.

Comment: @cfr "screw up the typesetting" what a thing to say! I am sure that you meant to say "honour the typesetting traditions of an earlier age"

Comment: @RobtAll good thing is, typewriter.sty requires luatex so you could use it with novel class.

Comment: I only get the error if I use TeX Live 2014. The linked answer clearly specifies that TeX Live 2015 or newer should be used.

Comment: @egreg post as answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not biting at that bait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to [Use LaTeX to simulate old typewriter written texts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344214/use-latex-to-simulate-old-typewriter-written-texts) you mention in comments clearly specifies that the code works only with TeX Live 2015 or later.

Indeed, I tried to compile your example with various releases of TeX Live and it fails only with TeX Live 2014 (and earlier).

Comment: Huh, yeah; the oddest part about it is that I did update MikTeX, but LuaTeX seemingly didn't update and was stuck on a 2013 release. Truly upsetting. Reinstalling MikTeX and admin-priv updating it fixed everything, and caught a few more un-updated packages and executables (why are they not updated? The update tool gives no error messages when I update even when it fails, it seems; but that's a question for a different time), and it works on, apparently, any LuaTeX version after 2015. +1, thanks