# How can I change the font in latex?

Tags: overleaf

My question somehow divides into two small questions.
I first do not get how I can change my font in latex (I'm working with overleaf). But in addition I wanted to ask if there is the font "univers". If not is there a possibility to integrate this font because we explicitly need this for our paper.

P.s. it is a math paper, so I have mathematic formulas in it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) See [What font packages are installed in TeX live?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59403/123129), [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/123129), [How to set the document font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439133/123129), [Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226/123129).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Overleaf, here is their support page listing some of the font options: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces#Reference_guide.

You can use them by calling the respective package: `\usepackage{lmodern}` (for the latin modern font).

It seems like Univers is not included (probably due to licensing), but Universalis (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/universalis) should look similar.

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % higher quality font encoding
\usepackage[sfdefault]{universalis} % load the font and set it to default

\begin{document}

This is a Universalis test. Here's some math: \[1+1=3\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, it worked!