# More control over arrows and shadows

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, flow-charts, shadows

I'm trying to make something similar to this shown in the figure below but I'm stuck with the text over the arrows and I couldn't make those shadows and thank you so much !

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning} 

\tikzset{%
    mytext/.style={font=\ttfamily\slshape\scriptsize,color=black}
    ,process/.style={mytext,
        ,rectangle
        ,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm
        ,text width=2.5cm
        ,text centered
        ,draw
        }
    ,decision/.style={mytext,
        ,diamond
        ,text width=1cm
        ,minimum height=0.9cm
        ,text centered
        ,draw
        ,fill=blue!10
        }
    ,arrow/.style={%
        ,very thick
        ,-Latex[round]
        }
    ,line/.style={%
        ,draw
        ,-latex'
        }
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\node  [decision,fill=cyan,draw=cyan] (dec1){Meet \\Goals?};
\node [process,fill=Gold,draw=Gold, above =2.6cm of dec1] (pro1) {Analyze/\\Re-analysis};
\node  [process, left = of pro1,fill=DeepSkyBlue,draw=DeepSkyBlue] (pro2){Design\\ Experiment};
\node  [process, below = of pro2,fill=Chartreuse2,draw=Chartreuse2] (pro3){Design\\ Experiment};
\node (pro4) [process, below = of pro3,fill=DarkOrchid2,draw=DarkOrchid2] {Charcterization\\ of Materials};
\node (pro5) [process, right =1.4cm of dec1,left color=Tomato,right color=Orange,draw=DarkOrange2] {Optimization\\design and scale up};
\node (proo) [text width=2.5cm,align = center ,mytext,right = of pro1]{\textbf{Traditional \\materials design\\process}}
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
\draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (pro4);
\draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro5);
        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning, shadows} 

\tikzset{%
    mytext/.style={font=\ttfamily\slshape\scriptsize,color=black}
    ,process/.style={mytext,
        ,rectangle
        ,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm
        ,text width=2.5cm
        ,text centered
        ,draw, drop  shadow={shadow xshift=-4pt, shadow yshift=-4pt}
    }
    ,decision/.style={mytext,
        ,diamond
        ,text width=1cm
        ,minimum height=0.9cm
        ,text centered
        ,draw
        ,fill=blue!10, drop  shadow={shadow xshift=0em, shadow yshift=-6pt}
    }
    ,arrow/.style={%
        ,very thick
        ,-Latex[round]
    }
    ,line/.style={%
        ,draw
        ,-latex'
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \node  [decision,fill=cyan,draw=cyan] (dec1){Meet \\Goals?};
        \node [process,fill=Gold,draw=Gold, above =2.6cm of dec1] (pro1) {Analyze/\\Re-analysis};
        \node  [process, left = of pro1,fill=DeepSkyBlue,draw=DeepSkyBlue] (pro2){Design\\ Experiment};
        \node  [process, below = of pro2,fill=Chartreuse2,draw=Chartreuse2] (pro3){Design\\ Experiment};
        \node (pro4) [process, below = of pro3,fill=DarkOrchid2,draw=DarkOrchid2] {Charcterization\\ of Materials};
        \node (pro5) [process, right =1.4cm of dec1,left color=Tomato,right color=Orange,draw=DarkOrange2] {Optimization\\design and scale up};
        \node (proo) [text width=2.5cm,align = center ,mytext,right = of pro1]{\textbf{Traditional \\materials design\\process}};
        \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[right, pos=0.4]{\textbf {No}}(pro1);
        \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
        \draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (pro4);
        \draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (dec1);
        \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[above, pos=0.4]{\textbf {Yes}}(pro5);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT **

You can also change the color of the drop shadow

```
drop  shadow={shadow xshift=0em, 
               shadow yshift=-6pt, 
               top color=red,
               bottom color=black,}
```

and the output

[image]

Comment: can i change the font ?

Comment: as a principle the answer is limited to the original question and should be accepted as such - a new query  should invite a new question so as to attract a larger audience - notwithstanding to change the font edit the syntax -     `mytext/.style={font=\ttfamily\slshape\scriptsize,color=black}`

Comment: for more on fonts -- https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces - or - https://latex-tutorial.com/changing-font-style/ - or - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656343/how-can-i-change-the-font-in-latex - or - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document

Comment: @BROK did the  answer meet the requirement stated in the question - if so please upvote/ accept the answer