Generating a Font Showcase PDF for Effortless Font Exploration and Review
I'm familiar with the process of listing installed fonts, but I'm interested in creating a PDF that showcases each font face/family's appearance for easier review and browsing (. I refer to fonts that are installed and can be used by TeX. This functionality is akin to what many font websites, such as Google Fonts offer.
I would like to avoid the need for listing the fonts, then write a TeX file that uses them and finally render it. A dynamic approach will be great.

Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249140?

There exist also the fonttable and unicodefonttable packages if you want to output all glyphs of a font

@Thérèse the tex file is hard-coded and there is a need to know the fonts in order to update the file. this is like the chicken and the egg :(

@JasperHabicht followed the links but i couldn't understand how to benefit from it.

If the suggestions in the comments don't help you, consider making your question more clear. So, you want to automatically list the installed fonts on your system (or of some directory?) and show them in a PDF with some example sentence, one line for each font? Is this what you're after? Note that TeX has access to fonts that your system has no access to, so it would be a first step to clarify which fonts you are after exactly.

Was about to say: which fonts? Are you using system fonts with a unicode engine? Unicode fonts from a TeX install? Type 1? Bitmap? (Hopefully not bitmap!) Even given a list, it isn't straightforward. If you typeset a sentence, symbol fonts may produce nothing but warnings. If you're interested in maths fonts, you likely want a different sample again. A decorative font may have only capitals --- or only some capitals --- or only lower case.  Do you want Latin, Greek, CJK, Cyrillic ...? For (pdf)TeX, which text font encoding, if you are listing text fonts? OT1? T1? T2A? LY1? Or ...?

The Font Catalog is the best general resource for information about fonts available in TeX distributions, at least for text in Latin script. But there's a reason that sampler was done by hand, keeps breaking and doesn't auto-update:  traditional TeX fonts are a tangle of historical decisions, new developments, compatibility fixes and usability compromises. I'm sure somebody could write an automated parser to generate a list. But I'm pretty sure there's none extant. And, frankly, it would be a thankless task for scant benefit. And it wouldn't catch lots of fonts available with unicode engines.

@JasperHabicht apologies for being unclear and thank you for the guidance. i've edited my question and i hope that now it is clearer.

@cfr i didn't know that it is really such a hard thing, i thought it should be very straightforward and i am surprised there is nothing like that already :)

We figured you wanted fonts which are installed and can be used by TeX. Are you aware that unicode engines can use almost any opentype font installed for your OS, which includes most truetype fonts as well as things like .ttc etc.? Because you seem to think TeX fonts are a breed apart - which used to be true and still is for pdfTeX/TeX - but isn't at all for the other engines.

@cfr isn't "I refer to fonts that are installed and can be used by TeX" clarify that? anyhow, could you please share a solution if you have any

I just explained not. A unicode engine can use fonts installed for your system. In that case, use Google Fonts. Anything available in opentype format you can use. You don't even have to install them. Or use the Font Catalogue for traditional TeX fonts. I already told you I don't know of a solution. But then I don't know what question you're asking. There was a recent question re. opentype fonts, so you could look at that. But you may or may not be asking about those so it may or may not help.

@Mr. it is still a bit confusing. Which "fonts that are installed and can be used by TeX" do you mean? Fonts for pdfTeX that can be used with a \usepackage{somefont} call? Or TrueType/OpenType fonts for XeTeX and LuaTeX that are used with the fontspec package? If it is pdfTeX fonts then you can use the Font Sampler from cfr in the linked answer, there are not really new fonts being added this way very often so that list is more or less final. If it is TTF/OTF fonts then you can use the font browser of your OS.

if i had all the answers to your questions, i wouldn't have asked here :)
