# Frutiger Font installation problem

Tags: fonts, installing

I've tried all stackexchange questions and now turn in desperation to asking myself:
I have a folder from Uni with tfm files, some map file.. etc. The installation says:

> 1. Copy the file frutiger.tar.gz to the Library-folder in your home directory.
> 2. Unzip the file.
> 3. Open a shell and execute:  sudo updmap —enable Map=~/Library/texmf/dvips/base/frutiger.map

Did that but now the compilation doesn't go through and I get a bunch of:

```
./section-introduction/introduction.tex:1: Font T1/pfr/m/n/72=pfrr8t  
> at 72.0pt  not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.  
> ./section-introduction/introduction.tex:2: Font  
> \T1/pfr/b/n/17.28=nullfont not
```

I've blindly tried the commands in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28658/frutiger-font-in-texlive-2011-and-lion-os).. no luck. Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254996/how-to-properly-set-font-for-document

Comment: @JPi this only tells me how to set fonts - am I wrong? The template already exists and works on my colleague's computer. The font is set with \fontfamily{pfr}

Comment: @JPi do you know any other place to ask this? kind of have to get this resolved :-/

Comment: This is the right place, I just don't own the font and don't know fonts well enough to be able to answer your question without being able to try.

Comment: If you are willing to compile with LuaLaTeX: `\usepackage{fontspec}` in the preamble. Then you can directly grab Open Type fonts (including the real Frutuger) without the need for TeX font metrics, or maps, or fd files. If willing to do so, see fontspec docs.

Comment: (1) and (3) are **terrible** advice. Not only should you not do that. Now you have done it, you should undo it. **Never use `updmap` to manage fonts unless you are willing to accept the consequences.** Not only that, but it is complete nonsense. It is most unclear what files you have, where you got them and what exactly you have done. You say you tried to follow the instructions. Well, did you or didn't you? What happened? What else did you do exactly? You need to unpick what you've done before thinking about installing these or you will just create more problems, even without Frutiger.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i/255711#255711. My answer there explains why you shouldn't do what you've been told to do and how to undo it if you read my answer too late. The Q & A covers both `updmap` and `getnonfreefonts`. Both should be avoided unless you have absolutely no choice, in which case you should seriously consider doing without the fonts before thinking about these as serious options. The instructions also mix root privileges with stuff in your personal tree, but that's almost minor.

Comment: The instructions in the answer to the question you linked to are outdated and no longer the recommended method. However, they are perfectly reasonable and would avoid all of the problems with the instructions you were given originally. However, they are useless unless you ensure you have undone anything you succeeded in doing with the first set of instructions. You have to do the undoing first.

Comment: Do note that unless you were given or have something like PFB or TTF or similar, you don't have the fonts. You only have metrics etc. TFM, MAP, ENC, FD etc. are all needed. But they are not the fonts themselves. So once you've undone what you did (if anything), check what you have. Installing support for a font you don't have access to is pointless at best.

Comment: @cfr thanks! I have read your answer - I have TFM, PFB and VF files (and a map file). Do I need more? Also: in the answer you recommend getnonfreefonts, but this is only for supported fonts of getnonfreefonts. how do you recommend I install Frutiger?

Comment: Running updmap only updates the map-file. But you message says that the tfm is not found. Did you put them in a place where it is found (e.g. in your local texmf in fonts/tfm)? Did you run mktexlsr?

Comment: @dv3 The point is to use `getnonfreefonts-sys` rather than `getnonfreefonts`, where applicable. In your case, that's not applicable. But you should use `updmap-sys` rather than `updmap` and install into TEXMFLOCAL rather than TEXMFHOME. You don't need to run `mktexlsr` if you installed into your personal tree (TEXMFHOME), but installing here is really not a good idea. Install into TEXMFLOCAL, run `mktexlsr` and then `updmap-sys` with the `--enable` line. (Better to change `updmap.cfg`, but that's more complicated, so probably easiest to stick to the `--enable` and just use the `-sys`.